# Google OAuth2 - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, google-oauth, uri, google-developers-console, google-analytics-data-api

I'm trying to run this project https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-data
I create new client OAuth 2.0 in Cloud Platform and I have the client_secret_code and I add uri http://localhost to the client OAuth settings
but I have this error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Comment: try to add http://127.0.0.1/ and also try with https

Comment: yes I tried this , but i still have the same error

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

> redirect_uri_mismatch

This is a configuration issue.  The redirect uri you added in google cloud console for your project must exactly match the one that your code is sending.

THe easiest solution is to check the error message it should tell you the Redirect uri that is missing simply add that in Google developer console.

[Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error.](https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ)